# Why is AWS shutting down automatically all the instances launched after the fifth?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I cannot start more than 5 instances. Is this normal behaviour for an AWS Educate account on us-east1?

Comment: What kind of instances? There are some limits for the "bigger" ones so you don't generate a VERY large expense (possibly without realizing). Check out the page for quota limits on EC2 and open a support ticket if you need more. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ec2-service.html

Comment: Not even more than 5 t2-micro ones which are supposedly free tier

Comment: One thing to realize about AWS is that it's not a basic hosting provider, it's a complex enterprise grade platform with hundreds of services. I've spent at least 500+ hours on AWS training over the past six or seven years, maybe triple that, not including partner training. I've also worked full time in AWS full time for a few years and I learn something new every day. AWS is fairly complex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. AWS has [Service Quotas](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-service-limits/) for a few reasons, including protecting their service, protecting new customers against bill shock, and preventing huge bills if an account is compromised.

As accounts get older and pay their bills the limits increase automatically, or you can request a limit increase.

The [AWS Service Quotas dashboard](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1) shows you your current limits, and makes it fairly easy to extend those limits.

Here's the dashboard for standard instance for my account, which is probably at least five years old. We can see the default limit is 5, but because my account is old and fairly well trusted I can launch 1848 instances. I'd actually rather it stayed at five, I could probably request that if I wanted to.

[image: EC2 instance limit]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there somewhere where I can verity that it's specifically 5 instances. Apparently some of my classmates didn't have this issue, so I'm trying to dig out the reason.

Comment: Thanks!! I see it now. I wonder how my classmates didn't have this issue then :/ is there a workaround?

Comment: In my post I link to service quotas which tells you exactly how to find the information, and I added a screenshot. It will differ between accounts. I did an AWS training course a few years ago, they gave us all new accounts, the limits varied between the accounts. Like I said in my answer you can request a higher limit, that can take from minutes to days.